# Как подгружать контент при изменениях в БД?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, php, javascript

Возможно ли как-то детектировать изменения в БД, например, появление новых записей, и подгружать их без перезагрузки страницы?

База данных -- Mysql

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы написали какую базу данных используете.

Comment: С мускулом не дружу, но, возможно, можно запомнить размер таблицы в приложении и, периодически, сравнивать что было и что есть. Если произошло изменение, то дальше дело техники (вроде тут на websocket-ы надо глянуть). Не исключаю также, что в самой СУБД предусмотрена какая-то такая функция.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123391/

Comment: так зачем события в mysql если там node ?(мало того это  не поможет - событие в базе не дернет фронт) приложение само знает когда обновились данные, если пользователь, которого обновление касается, подключен через socket.io, то надо просто сделать на его socket emit и всё. 

@Burack Habain
Тут скорее вопрос какой фреймворк на ноде вы используете. В теории просто вешаете событие на обновление модели и реализуете то о чем я написал выше. 

Если приложение на  php связанное с нодой через что-нибудь типа redis, то тоже самое - пришло обновление - дернули канал redis, а на ноде emit в сокет.

Comment: @eicto Давайте переключимся на mongodb. "приложение само знает когда обновились данные". А как приложение узнает о том, что запись "expire" и ее больше нет?

Comment: @alexandrr

а кто ее expire сделал ? Движок базы ? вот тут пишут что нормального способа для mongo нет. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014839/get-notification-for-changed-documents-in-mongodb
я бы не стал такой фичей пользоваться без крайней нужды.

Answer (score 1):

После получения данных из БД запоминаем количество вернувшихся результатов.
Регулярно ..хотя бы 1 раз в 30 секунд делаем аякс запрос на количество записей в БД, если вернется количество отличное от ранее запомненных, загружаем данные сравниваем с тем что имеем, вносим изменения в отображение, запоминаем новое количество результата. Если же не было изменений то просто продолжаем ждать изменений.

Если же есть необходимость в отслеживании изменений именно в ячейках строк, то можно н а php сделать расчет CRC и его сравнивать с CRC хранящимся у клиента. В случае не совпадения запрашиваем данные и сверяем с нашими в поисках того что изменилось.